# mprotect fails after some number of calls

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program where I allocate a block of memory, and then selectively change the protection of page-sized and page-aligned subsets of the block. But when I try to call `mprotect` on parts of the memory that are > 8 pages into the block, `mprotect` fails with the error "Cannot allocate memory".

Here is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int n_pages = 12;
    const int page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);   // 4096
    const int block_size = n_pages * page_size;     // 65536

    char* block_addr = (char*)aligned_alloc(page_size, block_size);
    char* chunks[n_pages];
    char* pointer = block_addr;

    for (int n = 0; n < n_pages; n++) {
        pointer = pointer + (n * page_size);
        chunks[n] = pointer;
    }
    std::cout << "Set chunks read-only.\n";
    for (int n = 0; n < n_pages; n++) {
        if (mprotect(chunks[n], page_size, PROT_READ) != 0) {
            std::cerr << n+1 << '/' << n_pages << ' '
                      << "mprotect failed: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Set chunks read/write.\n";
    for (int n = 0; n < n_pages; n++) {
        if (mprotect(chunks[n], page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) != 0) {
            std::cerr << n+1 << '/' << n_pages << ' '
                      << "mprotect failed: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        }
    }
    free(block_addr);
}
```

This consistently fails for chunks n>8, giving the following message:

```
Set chunks read-only.
9/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
10/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
11/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
12/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
Set chunks read/write.
9/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
10/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
11/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
12/12 mprotect failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862825/getting-cannot-allocate-memory-error) in which the OP seems to get the same error as I, where [David Hammen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774499/david-hammen) usefully provides some hints to the source of the problem, but I don't really understand what he is talking about. Unfortunately OP doesn't provide their code so we can't know exactly what they were doing or how they fixed it.

So basically my question is: Why does `mprotect` produce that error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: "*I don't really understand what he is talking about*" - what exactly is unclear?

Comment: The problem is that `ENOMEM` (the error you get) can mean three different things, and it's not always easy to know which is meant. Have you read the description in [the `mprotect` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html)? Can you eliminate one or preferably two of the cases there?

Comment: @melpomene I don't understand what he meant by making sure pages are mapped, and what I means for a page to be, or not to be mapped :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes I did read the man pages, but I don't yet know how to eliminate some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    pointer = pointer + (n * page_size);
```

This line looks very suspicious. It should probably be either

```
    pointer = block_addr + (n * page_size);
```

or

```
    chunks[n] = pointer;  // need to assign to chunks[n] first
    pointer = pointer + page_size;
```

Otherwise `pointer` will walk off (in steps of 0, 1 (= 0 + 1), 3 (= 0 + 1 + 2), 6 (= 0 + 1 + 2 + 3), ...) into memory that doesn't belong to your process because you didn't allocate it (i.e. it's "unmapped"). This would explain why `mprotect` fails for the last couple of chunks.

Comment: Wow so simple, there things just need a fresh pair of eyes some times :) thanks a lot.